# AJAX Post method not hitting controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can anyone point me here, what's wrong I am doing? my controller not hitting on Ajax post

Ajax Code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#btncreate').click(function () {
          var projectid = $("#txtprojectid").val();
          var financetype = $("#txtfinancetype").val();
          var actualcost = $("#txtactualcost").val();
          $.ajax({
              url: 'Projects/CreateFinanceItems?pid=' + projectid + "&ft=" + financetype + "&ac=" + actualcost,
              datatype: 'json',
              success: function (response) {
                  alert("Yes");
                  if (response != null) {
                      $('#displayproContainer').load('/Projects/PartialprojectFinanceItem');
                  }
              },
              error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                  alert(xhr.status);
                  alert(thrownError);
              }
          })
        });
    });        
    </script>
```

Controller Code

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateFinanceItems(string pid, string ft, string ac)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: You aren’t specifying POST in your `ajax` call. jQuery defaults to GET, not POST.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using jQuery? Everything you’re doing here can be done with built-in browser functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all , you have forget to specify the type of request in your Ajax. the default one is Get.
Second thing you have to start the url of the request with / which means the root URl of the site followed by the path of of the Action result.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#btncreate').click(function () {
          var projectid = $("#txtprojectid").val();
          var financetype = $("#txtfinancetype").val();
          var actualcost = $("#txtactualcost").val();
          $.ajax({
              url: '/Projects/CreateFinanceItems?pid=' + projectid + "&ft=" + financetype + "&ac=" + actualcost,
              type: 'POST',
              datatype: 'json',
              success: function (response) {
                  alert("Yes");
                  if (response != null) {
                      $('#displayproContainer').load('/Projects/PartialprojectFinanceItem');
                  }
              },
              error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                  alert(xhr.status);
                  alert(thrownError);
              }
          })
        });
    });        
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you Absi, its working. I know I am doing silly mistake but not able to find it..:)